How to receive a UDP packet over raw scokets in c++ in windows?
I tried to receive a UDP packet with the following function:
int UDP::recv(byte* data, const uint16_t dataLen, uint16_t srcPort, IPV4& srcIp)
{
    const size_t totalHeadersLen = IP_HEADERS_SIZE + UDP_HEADERS_SIZE;

    byte* recvBuffer = new byte[UINT16_MAX];
    sockaddr_in srcAddr;
    int srcAddrSize = sizeof(srcAddr);

    while (true) // Keep receiving until reaching a valid packet
    {
        // Receive the packet
        int packetSize = recvfrom(
            _socket,
            reinterpret_cast<char*>(recvBuffer),
            UINT16_MAX,
            0,
            reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&srcAddr),
            &srcAddrSize);

        // Check for errors
        if (packetSize == SOCKET_ERROR || packetSize < totalHeadersLen)
        {
            delete[] recvBuffer;
            throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(WSAGetLastError()));
        }

        // Parse IP header (20 bytes for IPv4)
        const byte* ipHeader = recvBuffer;

        // Extract source IP
        srcIp[0] = ipHeader[12];
        srcIp[1] = ipHeader[13];
        srcIp[2] = ipHeader[14];
        srcIp[3] = ipHeader[15];

        const byte* udpHeader = recvBuffer + IP_HEADERS_SIZE;

        UDPHeaders headers;
        headers.srcPort = ntohs(*reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(udpHeader));
        headers.dstPort = ntohs(*reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(udpHeader + 2));
        headers.length = ntohs(*reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(udpHeader + 4));
        headers.checksum = ntohs(*reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(udpHeader + 6));

        // Check if the destination port matches the local port
        if (headers.dstPort != _localPort)
        {
            // Ignore this packet
            continue;
        }

        // Set the source port
        srcPort = headers.srcPort;

        // Calculate the checksum and verify it matches
        size_t receivedDataLen = headers.length - UDP_HEADERS_SIZE;
        uint16_t checksum = calcChecksum(headers, srcIp, _localAddr, recvBuffer + totalHeadersLen, receivedDataLen);
        if (checksum != headers.checksum)
        {
            // Ignore this packet
            continue;
        }

        // Verify data length and buffer size
        if (dataLen < receivedDataLen)
        {
            delete[] recvBuffer;
            throw std::runtime_error("Data buffer is too small.");
        }

        // Copy the UDP payload to the provided buffer
        std::memcpy(data, recvBuffer + totalHeadersLen, receivedDataLen);

        break;
    }

    delete[] recvBuffer;
    return 0;
}

It blocks on the recvfrom function.
The creation of the socket is in another function.
Here is the creation part:
_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, POROTO_ID);
if (_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    WSACleanup();
    throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(WSAGetLastError()));
}

struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = 0;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


if (bind(_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    closesocket(_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    throw std::runtime_error(std::to_string(WSAGetLastError()));
}

The packet that I was trying to receive was successfully sent (I doublechecked with Wireshark).
The only way I found to solve this problem is by implementing the network layer (IPV4), which I prefer not to.

Why do you want to use raw sockets on the Windows API ? (the windows API is notoriously "C" like) What do you really want to achieve?  Because probably there are better ways than to use raw sockets

The usual way to receive an IPv4 UDP packet would be with an IPv4 UDP socket (aka socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);.  Receiving it with a raw socket is much less common and trickier to implement correctly, so there should be a really good reason to do it that way (unless you're just doing it that way deliberately, as a learning exercise).

Could you possibly distill this down to / turn this into a [mre] please?

My goal is to create UDP from scratch, so I can't really use the SOCK_DGRAM option. I will try to turn it into a minimal reproducible example later today.
